# How can I run git filter-branch on the root commit?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I'm trying to clean up a private project so I can publish it - removing miscellaneous files from the history, etc.

I'm trying to remove a Makefile with `git filter-branch`. Here's the command line I'm using:

```
$ git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git update-index --remove Makefile' 08a7d1..HEAD
```

However, when I run `git log -- Makefile`, it shows the Makefile being added in the root commit, then being removed in the commit immediately following the root commit.

How can I get `git filter-branch` to run on the root commit as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the starting commit in the commit range you specified (`08a7d1..HEAD`) isn't inclusive. So basically it's saying "everything that happened *after* `08a7d1`, all the way up to `HEAD`."

Passing the commit range to `git filter-branch` is optional. If you omit it, it will be run on *all* commits, all the way back to and including the root. So:

```
$ git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git update-index --remove Makefile'
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change ONLY the root commit, for such change the solution I came up was using a (linux) IF statement inside the filter

```
# Change ca1215d5bfc9928ef72c92f10dd53d3bc67c6274 for your own root commit ID
git filter-branch --env-filter '
if [ $GIT_COMMIT = ca1215d5bfc9928ef72c92f10dd53d3bc67c6274 ]
then
    # GIT Changes here
fi'
```

Comment: nice tip! just want to note that `if` statement isn't a "Linux" statement. it's a Unix shell construct and will work on pretty much any operating system that vaguely looks like a Unix, including Linux, the *BSDs and macOS.